# How to retrieve multiple values from redux state using find method

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to get the Redux state into my component using **mapStateToProps()** function as shown below:

```
function mapStateToProps({ posts, comments }, ownProps) {
    return {
      post: Object.values(posts.posts).find(post => post.id ===ownProps.match.params.id),
      comment: Object.values(comments.comments).find(comment => comment.parentId ===ownProps.match.params.id)};
}
```

Now, the problem is there are more than one comment in my state, and since **find()** method returns only the first element of the array, I am not able to retrieve the other comments.So, how do I get all the comments from the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method instead. Filter returns an array of items that match the criteria.

```
function mapStateToProps({ posts, comments }, ownProps) {
    return {
      post: Object.values(posts.posts).find(post => post.id === ownProps.match.params.id),
      comment: Object.values(comments.comments).filter(comment => comment.parentId === ownProps.match.params.id)
    };
}
```